# Is a USB Key an SSD?

Tags: external-hard-drive, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are USB flash drives so much slower than solid-state drives?](https://superuser.com/questions/253579/why-are-usb-flash-drives-so-much-slower-than-solid-state-drives)

Hello, i was reading this article: http://www.pcworld.fr/2011/06/06/materiel/stockage/super-talent-usb-3-0-express-rc8/515991/ and i was wondering if a USB key is already an SSD? Is that a new Marketing crap they just invented or am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, yes, although they have slower read/write speeds compared to their bigger internal SSD brothers.

In this picture the label "4" shows the actual storage chip, and as mentioned below "2" is the controller board. An internal disk will have many storage chips, at probably a higher capacity.
[image]

Comment: Actually the SSD is a combination of 2, the controller chip, and 4, the flash memory chip.

Comment: 6 is just an indicator of activity, like Ignacio said, 2 and 4 makes the solid state storage.

Comment: How in Thors' name did I get that wrong? Changed.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia:

> "A solid-state drive (SSD) is a data storage device that uses solid-state memory to store persistent data with the intention of providing access in the same manner of a traditional block i/o hard disk drive."

So yes a usb stick is a SSD.