# Does using zfs with (mirrored) usb drives have any drawbacks except speed?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, ssd, zfs

I'm interested in using zfs with usb drives for storage on a linux desktop machine. I already have a lot of large external drives so this will be cheaper than buying new internal drives. I might have to use a usb hub to connect the usb drives. Does using zfs with (mirrored) usb drives have any drawbacks except [speed](https://superuser.com/questions/448908/usb-3-0-slower-than-sata-for-ssd)? I'm first and foremost interested in any issue that may negate the data integrity benefits of zfs but comments on other potential issues would also be appreciated.

EDIT: I found a potential [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185702/92702).

Comment: Note an answer per se, but something to be wary of. You say "Linux desktop machine". Most desktop systems have non-[ECC RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory), which can lead to [total data loss](http://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/ecc-vs-non-ecc-ram-and-zfs.15449/) when combined with ZFS (particularly its self-healing functionality). This is not just theoretical; it actually *happens* to people. **If you are going to use ZFS** then make sure you have ECC RAM installed and working. ZFS can work in non-ECC RAM, but in such a setup, the failure mode is catastrophic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/maczfs/wiki/GettingStarted
"Be aware of issues inherent in USB and avoid it wherever possible, or be careful."

This is for maczfs, I assume this is also the case is for zfs on other OSs. In other words, yes there seems to be serious drawbacks/risks you're exposed to when using usb drives with zfs.