# Why are USB flash drives slower than SATA SSD's?

Tags: ssd, performance, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

As a broad generalization current generation SSD's have write performance of around 500MB/s.

Premium USB flash drives have write performance of circa 170MB/s, looking at Kingston Predator and Patriot Magnum as example.

In sizes of 256GB/512GB the of the high end USB flash drivers price per GB is about the same as for SSD's.

Considering that some of the SSD's come in form factors small enough to fit inside a USB flash drive and USB3 supports 5Gbps, I do not understand why USB flash drivers are so much slower. Some also claim "SSD controllers".

I looked at all the high end USB flash drives and some claim write performance of 400MB/s, however all independent reviews only ever achieve a little under 200MB/s.

Has anyone tried an SSD in a SATA to USB adaptor.

If it isnt the drive where is the bottleneck?

PS, I wish to backup 200GB of data in as short a time as possible on a regular basis. Only option is via USB. I bought a Kingston Predator 512GB which does 170MB/s, I would like 500MB/s to speed it up.

Can I just buy an SSD and put it in a generic usb3 enclosure?

If I can why do none of the manufacturers do this?

Comment: SSD typically have a significantly more capable (and expensive) controller on board than USB pen drives. They typically also carry more flash chips (which can be written in paralel). Still, what is the practical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are USB flash drives so much slower than solid-state drives?](http://superuser.com/questions/253579/why-are-usb-flash-drives-so-much-slower-than-solid-state-drives)

Answer (score 2):

I use my older 256GB Samsung 830 SSD in an USB 3 enclosure and get around 430MB/s.

[image]

To get this speed you have to use an enclosure that supports [USB Attached SCSI (UASP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI) otherwise you get only 250MB/s (USB Mass Storage Bulk-Only Transport (BOT))