# Will Compressing an Entire USB Flash Drive Actually Increase Performance?

Tags: usb, performance, usb-flash-drive, compression, usb-2

As we know, USB flash drives are generally [*very slow* in data transfer rates](https://superuser.com/questions/253579/why-are-usb-flash-drives-so-much-slower-than-solid-state-drives). USB 3 has significantly increased the rates data transfers, but it's still much slower than even traditional mechanical HDDs - and many people still do not own the hardware to benefit from the new revision.

Also, compression/decompression slows down opening and saving files, but I would imagine that this is only true for I/O on an HDD/SSD/SSHD where the transfer rates are faster than the rates of a USB drive.

Is anyone aware of any performance tests that shows potential benefits from compressing an entire USB flash drive (particularly USB 2.0)? I would imagine that a computer's processor can decompress a file much faster than the USB can read an uncompressed file - so the larger the compression is on a USB - the less time it would take to read while the much faster processor can decompress a file quickly.

I would like to add a side note that I do not want to consider highly compressed media such as `.jpg` or encoded video where there will be little to no benefit from further compression. I am mostly talking about compression that would be in the range of 10%+ savings in disk space.

Comment: I believe the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/411720/how-does-ntfs-compression-affect-performance) question should also apply to yours. The distinction between a HDD and a (slower) USB flash drive isn't too significant here.

Comment: To that end, I am voting to close this question as a duplicate. If you believe it is not a duplicate, and that the USB flash drive case would lead to different answers, please edit your question so the question can be reopened.

Comment: You might also find the numbers provided in [Performance Evaluation
Of FileSystems Compression Features by Solomon Legesse](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/42152/thesis.pdf) useful.

Comment: @Bob I believe I can assert the answer from your link. Thank you for the reference.